# Arduino isn't seeing PN532 chip

Tags: arduino, rfid

I am having an issue with the **PN532 reader**:
I would like to use the module with an **Arduino Uno**, and read 13.56 MHz tags.

I choose the **UART connection**, and soldered pin, as shown here:

[image: pins photo]

[image: Front of the chip]

***EDIT, the wires are now in the opposite directions**

The problem is that the **Arduino doesn't see the chip**, and returns "**no PN532 board were found.**"

I also tried the I2C connection, and it doesn't work either. It's super weird

I did the following:

- Change the binary switches, but they are in the correct position
- Stick the wires at 90 degrees (to avoid interferences with antenna)
- resolder the pins
- change the pins in the Arduino code
- physically switch the pins

Here is the code (for the UART):

```
/* When the number after #if set as 1, it will be switch to SPI Mode*/
#if 0
  #include <SPI.h>
  #include <PN532_SPI.h>
  #include "PN532.h"

  PN532_SPI pn532spi(SPI, 10);
  PN532 nfc(pn532spi);

/* When the number after #elif set as 1, it will be switch to HSU Mode*/
#elif 1
  #include <PN532_HSU.h>
  #include <PN532.h>
      
  PN532_HSU pn532hsu(Serial);
  PN532 nfc(pn532hsu);

/* When the number after #if & #elif set as 0, it will be switch to I2C Mode*/
#else 
  #include <Wire.h>
  #include <PN532_I2C.h>
  #include <PN532.h>
  #include <NfcAdapter.h>
  
  PN532_I2C pn532i2c(Wire);
  PN532 nfc(pn532i2c);
#endif
  
void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Hello!");

  nfc.begin();

  uint32_t versiondata = nfc.getFirmwareVersion();
  if (! versiondata) {
    Serial.print("Didn't find PN53x board");
    while (1); // halt
  }
  
  // Got ok data, print it out!
  Serial.print("Found chip PN5"); Serial.println((versiondata>>24) & 0xFF, HEX); 
  Serial.print("Firmware ver. "); Serial.print((versiondata>>16) & 0xFF, DEC); 
  Serial.print('.'); Serial.println((versiondata>>8) & 0xFF, DEC);
  
  // Set the max number of retry attempts to read from a card
  // This prevents us from waiting forever for a card, which is
  // the default behaviour of the PN532.
  nfc.setPassiveActivationRetries(0xFF);
  
  // configure board to read RFID tags
  nfc.SAMConfig();
    
  Serial.println("Waiting for an ISO14443A card");
}
```

I have absolutely no idea of why it isn't working. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are your 4 wires as in the pictures? Should be 180°, out of the board ... What is the "recto" of the PN532 board?

Comment: Tried this? https://how2electronics.com/interfacing-pn532-nfc-rfid-module-with-arduino/ If you use the "serial" mode, you should choose rx and tx other the D0 and D1 used by Arduino serial downloader.

Comment: Yes my 4 wires are exactly as in the pictures. If I use the RX and TX pins, the arduino will either send nothing to the serial monitor, or say no chip found. I'm starting to think that my chip is broken

Comment: Wires should not pass just under the board ... Change these first. If you can, check the current supply. Have you tried my link?

Comment: Yes i followed the tutorial, and uploaded the code, it doesn't work. For the wires, if i put them on the front side, isn't that worst ? Cause the rfid signal will go through the the wires ? From the red chip to the card, and back.

Comment: Wait, when you said not just under the board, you mean that they should go straight down ?

Comment: As this ... out off the bord ... https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DM1c.jpg

Comment: Ok did it, no changes